# What tense to use with "when" clause

Tags: tenses, clauses

I've just listened to the song and memories have come flooding back. The question is what tense to use to describe what have just happened in a sentence: when I've heard this song memories had come flooding back. Am I correct?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). Hi Anfisacat, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). FWIW: *when I heard this song memories came flooding back* is more usual; the present perfect is a bit awkward with "when", but I'd use *when I've heard this song memories [before], would come flooding back.* :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct:

> When I've heard this song, memories had come flooding back.

It would be correct about a future statement with a slight change:

> When I've heard this song, memories *will* come flooding back.

But if you want to talk about the past, you would need to change a couple of things:

> When I [] heard this song, memories *came* flooding back.

Comment: I can't think of a sentence in past tense starting with "when", though I may be wrong.

Comment: @ALambentEye I used such a sentence at the end of my answer. ;) Also: *When I went to the store, it was without my wallet.* *When I studied for the exam, it was immediately after I'd written an essay.*

Comment: It sounds off to me, but I'll take your word.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not, you are combining future (When...) and past tenses (have heard, had come)

The closest sentence to your original would be

> Once I heard this song, memories came flooding back.

but that would imply you're hearing the song for the first time.

> Upon hearing this song, memories came flooding back.

may be more suitable.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I should've seen the dependent clauses.